# VSCode Python extension cannot find python after update on windows 10

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I updated the VSCode "python" extension this morning and now it cannot find python. I installed python to "C:\Python37\" and added it to path. Running python from CMD works, such as:

[image: python from cmd]

So there is nothing wrong with my python installation. Launching VSCode I see this in the bottom right:
[image: vscode extension]

If I click on "select python interpreter" it shows where I tried to hard code the python path in settings.json, but I can't select anything.

```
{"python.pythonPath": "C:/Python37/python.exe"}
```

I found a thread on google that seems relevant to my problem here:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/3535

Going through those steps, I enabled dev tools and went up the error logs to find the first error, which appears here:

```
console.ts:137 [Extension Host] Error Python Extension: 2020-02-14 15:16:22: Failed to get interpreter information for 'C:/Python37/python.exe' [Error: spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe; ENOENT   at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:264:19)   at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16) at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:9)] {  errno: 'ENOENT',  code: 'ENOENT',  syscall: 'spawn C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe;',  path: 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe;',  spawnargs: [    '-c',    '"C:/Python37/python.exe" ' +      '"c:\\Users\\tbarker1\\.vscode\\extensions\\ms-python.python-2020.2.63072\\pythonFiles\\interpreterInfo.py"'  ],  cmd: '"C:/Python37/python.exe" ' +    '"c:\\Users\\tbarker1\\.vscode\\extensions\\ms-python.python-2020.2.63072\\pythonFiles\\interpreterInfo.py"'}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles upon this thread from google, I solved the problem by:

> click on the extensions tab in vscode
>   right click on the python extension
>   click "install a previous version"
>   installed an older version from roughly 6 months prior